# Wildfly Spring + Hibernate SessionFactory NoSuchMethodError

Tags: spring, hibernate, wildfly, nosuchmethoderror, sessionfactory

This is my configuration:

- Application Server: 
  jsboss Wildfly 9.X -> (it has hibernate module with version : 4)
- Legacy spring application : spring version: 2.0.6 working on hibernate 3.2.6.ga

I have to develope a Rest service calling some dao functions.

In the snippet code there are some key statements of my legacy app-context.xml:

```
<bean id="groupDao" class="my.package.dao.UserDaoHibernate">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" parent="sessionFactoryTemplate"/>

<bean id="sessionFactoryTemplate" abstract="true"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="mappingResources">
        <list>
            <value>User.hbm.xml</value>             
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass"
        value="my.package.hibernate.Configuration" />       
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.use_sql_comments">false</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size">64</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">1</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.release_mode">after_transaction</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">my.package.connection.MyDBHibernateConnectionProvider</prop>
        </props>
    </property> 
</bean>
```

This is my UserDaoHibernate class:

```
public class UserDaoHibernate extends org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport implements UserDao
{   
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public User findByUsername(String username, boolean allowProfileUser)
    {
        List<User> users = getHibernateTemplate().findByNamedQueryAndNamedParam(
            "User.findByUsername", "user", username);
        ...
        return user;
    }
```

In order to avoid api conflicts i added a deployment descriptor:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="org.hibernate" /> 
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

When i run the code i cacth this exception:

```
Caused by: org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hibernate.SessionFactory.openSession()Lorg/hibernate/classic/Session;
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.rethrow(ResponseWriter.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.internal.ResponseWriter.failure(ResponseWriter.java:238)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:486)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:460)
```

Entering the code in debug mode and inspecting the sessionFactory inside UserDao i see that its type is:

```
org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl
```

which is an Hibernate4 implementation. The internal package is not contained in the Hibernate 3 core. So in some way WildFly is overlapping its hibernate implementation.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You also might want to exclude the packages for JPA (which might pull in hibernate again).

Comment: do you mean the jpa module?

Comment: correct, as that depends on hibernate so that might pull it in again.

Comment: i have updated  <exclusions> <module name="org.hibernate" />           <module name="org.jboss.as.jpa" /></exclusions> ... but nothing... same exception...